Very low crawl requests in crawl stats despite high count of indexed pages in GSC
My website is having very low daily average crawl requests (~20k/day) whereas approximately 300K pages are indexed.


What can be the reason for this and how can I increase the daily crawl requests so that fresh data is available with google to show on SERP

It could depend on the quality of the content, the server performance. Check that there are no duplicate pages, and optimize the site for search engines. These are the two ways to influence and try to increase the crawl budget.
